# Issue with Paging3 library after calling refresh() on paged list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-3

**What's my problem:**

After invoking refresh() on paged list, the list is not being fetched fully.

**Here is behaviour for initial load:**

1. Page 0 is being fetched with size 30
2. Page 1 is being fetched
3. Page 2 is being fetched
4. Page 3 is being fetched

**Here is behaviour for refresh behaviour:**

1. Page 3 is being fetched with size 30 *(i guess here is the issue)*
2. Page 2 is being fetched with size 15
3. Page 1 is being fetched with size 15
4. Page 0 is being fetched with size 15

The issue is that after refreshing, the 4th page fetches with size 30, which is empty (if fetched with size 15 its not empty as size parameter determines how much pages there is)

**Expected behaviour:**

After calling refresh() whole list is fetched

**PagingSource:**

```kotlin
class ClaimsAndReturnsPagingSource @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: PagedRepository,
    private val emptyList: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    private val pharmacyId: Int,
    private val claimsAndReturnsList: (List<ClaimsAndReturnsList>, Int) -> Unit,
    private val totalCount: (Int) -> Unit,
    private val preferencesDataSource: PreferencesDataSource,
    private val dispatcherIO: CoroutineDispatcher
) : PagingSource<Int, ClaimsAndReturnsList>() {
    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, ClaimsAndReturnsList>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
            val anchorPage = state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)
            anchorPage?.prevKey?.plus(1) ?: anchorPage?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, ClaimsAndReturnsList> {
        return withContext(dispatcherIO) {
            try {
                val page = params.key ?: 0
                val response = repository.getClaimsAndReturns(
                    page = page,
                    size = params.loadSize,
                    pharmacyId = pharmacyId
                )
                val mappedResponseContent = response.content.map { item ->
                    item.copy(
                        returnOrderType = mapToFullName(item.returnOrderType)
                    )
                }
                claimsAndReturnsList(mappedResponseContent, page)
                emptyList(response.first && response.empty)
                totalCount(response.totalElements)
                LoadResult.Page(
                    data = mappedResponseContent,
                    prevKey = if (response.first) null else page - 1,
                    nextKey = if (response.last || BuildConfig.FLAVOR == "mock") null else page + 1
                )
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                LoadResult.Error(e)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                LoadResult.Error(e)
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                LoadResult.Error(e)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                LoadResult.Error(e)
            } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
                LoadResult.Error(e)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i commend you for catching every individual exception, except for just a generic e: Exception. you're a better person than me :)